# Use of preposition after the word illustration

Tags: prepositions

He made a few illustrations of/for/to the longish poem of P.B. Shelley.

How does meaning differ with the different prepositions?

Answer (score 3):

> He made a few illustrations of the longish poem of P.B. Shelly.

He is creating illustrations---as in pictures---that display Shelly's poem.

> He made a few illustrations for the longish poem of P.B. Shelly.

He is creating illustrations that will be displayed with the text of Shelly's poem when the poem is published.

The sentence with "to" is not valid.